# Monitoring Picasso for IdlingResource in Espresso

Tags: android, picasso, android-testing, android-espresso

I want to be able to have `Espresso` monitor `Picasso` as an `IdlingResource` so that I can run `ViewMatcher`s once the image has been successfully loaded.

From navigating through the `Picasso` source code, I don't see why this isn't working. Here's what I tried:

```
Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context).build();
Field dispatcherField = Picasso.class.getDeclaredField("dispatcher");
dispatcherField.setAccessible(true);

try {
  Dispatcher dispatcher = (Dispatcher) dispatcherField.get(picasso);
  Espresso.registerLooperAsIdlingResource(dispatcher.dispatcherThread.getLooper());
} catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
  throw new PicassoHasBeenRefactoredException();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

onView(withId(R.id.image_view)).check(matches(withImage(R.drawable.drawable)));
```

(yes, I know, reflecting is icky, but I couldn't find another way of getting a handle on the `Looper`)

But it results in this error when trying to get the `Bitmap` from the `ImageView`:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.getBitmap()' on a null object reference
```

To check that the test is running as expected once an image has been loaded, I tried introducing a `Thread.sleep(1000)` in lieu of the `IdlingResource` check and it passed.

Is it safe to assume that the IdlingResource hasn't been set up correctly, and, more importantly, what would be the correct way of waiting for Picasso to finish loading before checking views with Espresso?

Comment: can't you use [onSucess callback](https://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/Callback.html#onSuccess--) from Picasso to setup your IdelingResource?

Comment: @RahulTiwari I don't want to modify any of the production code to accommodate the tests, unless you meant something else?

Comment: I was talking about using callbacks Picasso provide `onSuccess` and `onError` and getting rid of reflection if possible. So yes I was talking about  modifying the code, but it will not affect any functionality for sure.

Comment: It's a tradeoff. In my opinion setting up an idlingResource on production code is pretty harmless and leads you to a much simpler test code.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using an IdlingResource that checks if there are actions left.

Note that the IdlingResource must live in the same package as Picasso to gain access to a package-protected variable

```
package com.squareup.picasso;

public class PicassoIdlingResource implements IdlingResource, ActivityLifecycleCallback {
  protected ResourceCallback callback;

  WeakReference<Picasso> picassoWeakReference;

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "PicassoIdlingResource";
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isIdleNow() {
    if (isIdle()) {
      notifyDone();
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  public boolean isIdle() {
    return picassoWeakReference == null
            || picassoWeakReference.get() == null
            || picassoWeakReference.get().targetToAction.isEmpty();
  }

  @Override
  public void registerIdleTransitionCallback(ResourceCallback resourceCallback) {
    this.callback = resourceCallback;
  }

  void notifyDone() {
    if (callback != null) {
      callback.onTransitionToIdle();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityLifecycleChanged(Activity activity, Stage stage) {
    switch (stage) {
      case CREATED:
        picassoWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(Picasso.with(activity));
        break;
      case STOPPED:
        // Clean up reference
        picassoWeakReference = null;
        break;
      default: // NOP
    }
  }
}
```

I don't think using WeakReference is needed, but it doesn't hurt either.

Also, I've identified one case where it doesn't wait until Picasso finishes (when using *.load(null)*). So, use at your own risk and please come back if you improve it.

See gist for full details and usage (https://gist.github.com/Maragues/0c0db81a137c8d067396)

Comment: Thanks! The solution doesn't work correctly when moving between activities. To fix it I replaced states CREATED & STOPPED by **RESUMED & PAUSED**

Comment: Also I found that this introduces big delays (**up to 5 secs delay per image loaded**) because Espresso has a few seconds delay between re-checks. The solution is to force the recheck on PicassoIdlingResource like this example: https://gist.github.com/vaughandroid/e2fda716c7cf6853fa79#file-viewvisibilityidlingresource-java-L62

Comment: Thanks @SebasLG, I'm currently on another project, but I'll check your code once I get back to the old one.